# Tool for displaying relations among nested classes/structs

Tags: c++, c, structure, visualization

Frequently, a class/struct is dependent on other classes/structs, which in turn are dependent on other classes/structs. In big projects, this can easily lead to confusion. Is there a tool (preferably a simple text-only command-line tool) that can show how classes or structs are nested/aggregated/related? Support for inheritance is not needed...

Comment: text is nice.  But text, you have.  Drawings are more easily brain-parsed.

Comment: What do you mean "show how they are related?"  Dump out the nested structure of a class or struct, including the details of members?  One thing you could do in `gdb` is to print an instance of whatever your are interested in; the nested structure will be printed automatically.  GUI debuggers will probably have even nicer structure browsing features.

Comment: not simple or cli, but doxygen is great:  http://www.google.com/images?q=doxygen+class+diagram&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&rlz=1R1GGLL_en___US399&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=univ&ei=DZ9RTYmsOsLFgAfP0ai2CA&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ct=title&resnum=3&ved=0CDMQsAQwAg&biw=1728&bih=798

Answer (score 4):

I think **Doxygen** is the best solution, when combinated with graphviz's *dot*.

http://www.graphviz.org/

http://www.doxygen.org/

The configuration of Doxygen is carried out by a configuration text file, and after that, you can re-launch it as soon as any file has changed, even automatically from another tool.

Using Dot, you'll get diagrams of class relations.
Doxygen does also parse the files and colors its syntax, it is a matter of checking the configuration file for five minutes.

```
$ doxygen -g app.dox
[...edit app.dox]
$ doxygen app.dox
```

Answer (score 1):

GDB command - `ptype typename`

Print inheritance relationships as well as other information for type typename.